# Using JMS Connector on Mule

Tags: jms, mule

When using JMS connector on a Mule flow, the JMS request will be asynchronous or do I have to put the JMS connector inside Async Scope, and so the flow keep processing regardless the JMS request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asynchronous. No needed of `async` scope. For more information you can read https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/JMS+Transport+Reference

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep in asynchronous block

Ref: http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/asynchronous-message-processing-with-mule/
    https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/async-scope-reference

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP_Listener Configuration" />
 <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" numberOfConsumers="2" />
    <flow name="samplepocFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="** Triggered the flow ** ${name} ${name}" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[File file = new File("C://Users//schiraboina//Desktop//123.txt")
payload=file.getText()   ]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <logger message="Final Data #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
 <flow name="jms_message_sender">
     <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET, POST" />
     <set-payload value="JMS EXAMPLE" doc:name="Set Payload" />
     <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String" />
     <logger message="Sending message to queue" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="MyQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
        </async>
     <logger message="After JMS " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
 </flow>
 <flow name="jms_message_consumer">
  <jms:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="MyQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" />
    <logger message="Consuming Message from queue " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
 </flow>
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need to add the Async Scope. One of the links that you have just added on your answer says: "Some transports and connectors, like JMS or the VM transport, are asynchronous by default". So what @eddú is still correct!